# Is "12:30" (the time of day) an abstract noun?

Tags: nouns, numbers, time, parts-of-speech, abstract-nouns

Nothing else to add, I just want to make sure.

Comment: Don't make the mistake of assuming that a noun has to be a concrete noun or an abstract noun, Dee. They've been arguing about things like 'hole' (is it distinguishable by sight, or is it deducible, its surroundings being distinguishable by sight?) for years. I'd say that 12:30 has more of an 'existence' than a hole but less than a clock. But then we could start worrying about whether there is a deeper _referent_ (the actual instant in time) behind the unique identifier (12:30) assigned to it. Leave it to the psycholinguists.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Please edit to include context (why you are asking) and results of your prior research. The helpfulness of those facts is why you are not allowed to leave the description blank. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Times of day,when expressed as digits, are, in essence, numerals, and numerals, in the words of the ‘Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English’, ‘form a rather self-contained area of English grammar.’ Numerals aren’t nouns of any kind, because they cannot be modified in the way that nouns can be modified. We can’t speak of *a nice 12:30* or *the 12:30 I was looking at yesterday.*

Comment: *The worst seven o'clock I remember*? *The most enjoyable lunchtime for months*?

Comment: If it's just considered a number word, then it would be a determiner. As for the nouns not being modified in the way nouns are, how would you modify length, patience, love, etc... (the "idea" form of nouns, ie., abstract nouns), with an adjective?

Comment: @TimLymington. Sure, but those aren't numerals, and in any case _the worst seven o'clock_ is an unlikely, but not impossible, thing for anyone to say. I've edited my answer slightly in the hope of making it clearer.

Comment: @Dee; Truly, madly, deeply.  (OK, a cheap shot, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: The argument is seen to be contestable when one considers _noon_ and _midnight_: we can’t speak of _a nice noon_ or _the noon I was looking at / had yesterday_ either, yet these words, synonymous with time-descriptor numerals, are considered nouns. And some numerals are used in plural forms: _He was in his 80s in the 1960s_. _The temperature is in the mid-thirties_.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. The OED has numerous citations which show how both _noon_ and _midnight_ can be modified. They include ‘the noon of the day’, ‘youth's breathless noon’ and ‘the noon in Pall Mall’ for the first, and ‘summer midnights’, ‘the Arctic midnight’ and ‘the terrible midnight’ for the second. All this shows that numerals are hard to pin down in conventional grammatical terms, particularly when they occur as times of the day like _12:30_.

Comment: Yes - I'm arguing that meaning has at least as large a bearing on how we should regard these parts of speech as the forms of syntax they appear in. We switched from the illogical and confusing 12 pm to 12 noon - a compound noun? Though distribution _is_ quite disturbing: The Roaring Forties, Sweet Sixteen, The Famous Five (OK, Five must be a noun here), _The Billy of this story always coaxed from his soft-hearted mamma an extra half hour in the evening when the dreaded nine o'clock came_ (Internet); the 'six o'clock shadow' would argue for adjectival status - adjective or noun-modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've also spoken with a handful of English teachers and we've come to the conclusion that the time of day is abstract, as time itself is abstract. Reference point - I gave a quiz to my students and one of the questions was, "What is a proper noun?, definition - example". One example was "12:30". I know it's not a proper noun but I wanted to be able to tell him the correct answer. Can you see/touch 12:30?

Comment: @TimLymington — using those words with 'love' means you're using 'love' as a verb, not an abstract noun.

Comment: @Dee: the point I was frivolously expressing is that *deep and enduring love*, *patience as thin and fragile as eggshell* and *a length both surprising and unequalled* are acceptable and normal. If you say that analogies don't count, and any description of abstract qualities must be analogical, then certainly abstractions cannot be described; but I regard that as playing with words.

Comment: My students wouldn't understand that explanation. They need a definite answer for now. I teach in Asia. They're still grasping at basic English. Analogies are over most of their heads. Irregardless, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Is it breaktime yet?  Every breaktime is a great time!
I can replace this with:
It is 10:00 am yet?  Every 10:00 am is a great 10:00 am!
I call this a noun.